# Javascript method is not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, xml

My stylesheet is working on ie, however it isnt working on firefox. It gives an error such as:

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable @ 
>   TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.

Here is my code:

```
<script style="javascript">
    function displayRevision2() {
        for (i = 1; i & lt; j; i++) {
            foo = document.getElementById('row' + i).innerHTML;
            substring = foo.substr(0, foo.search("\n") - 1);
            //displayRevision(substring);   
            if (flag == 1) document.getElementById(substring).style.display = "";
            else document.getElementById(substring).style.display = "none";
        }
        if (flag == 1) flag = 0;
        else flag = 1;
    }
</script>
<script style="javascript">
    function dispTD(num) {
        rowtxt = '&lt;TD class="br" align="middle" id="row' + num + '">';
        document.write(rowtxt);
    }
</script>
<script style="javascript">
    function dispEndTD() {
        document.write("&lt;/TD>");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: is this working: `for(i=1; i&lt;j ;i++)` ?

Comment: Every variable in that code is global, and entities doesn't really work in JS

Comment: `style = "javascript"` ? where did you see this? I strongly think it is wrong syntax.

Comment: It is working only one time. I turned them global variables.

<script style="javascript">
flag=1;
j=1;
i=1;</script>

Comment: Can you show the order how these functions are called. Looks like `document.write()` was guilty here.

Comment: I see it so many times and it works. what should I use instead of "javascript"?

Comment: It's `type="text/javascript"`what you've seen...

Comment: You should use JavaScript, but I think you need to start from scratch with a good learning resource like the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) for example.

Comment: <TR>
 <script style="javascript">dispTD(j);</script>
 <xsl:value-of select="@StepNum"/>
 <script style="javascript">j++;</script>
 <script style="javascript">dispEndTD();</script>

Comment: Hmm... you maybe better to get familiar with [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write).

Comment: @merand How stubborn a man can be? Why you didn't follow my link above and read: "`Note: document.write (like document.writeln) does not work in XHTML documents...`". Instead you've been asking this same question three more times...

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the element the script is searching for does not exist on the document. Try to check if the scripts finds the element first **before directly accessing its attributes**.

```
fooElement = document.getElementById('row' + i);
if(fooElement) foo = fooElement.innerHTML;
```

Comment: @merand, because it is not present. Can you create a jsfiddle of your problem?

Comment: @merand, I would love to, but your fiddle is not working. There are separate sections for HTML, css and javascript. Please create a working fiddel first.

Comment: Yes I know but "document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle envioriment and might break your fiddle"